# how to convert or save a csv file into a txt file using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm learning Pyspark and I don't know how to save the sum of RDD values into a file. I've tried the code below unsuccessfully:

```
from typing import KeysView

counts = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(",")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

k=counts.keys().saveAsTextFile("out/out_1_2a.txt")
sc.parallelize(counts.values().sum()).saveAsTextFile('out/out_1_3.txt')
```

While I could save the keys into a file, I couldn't save the sum of the values. The error I get is: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Can someone help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See logic below -

```
counts = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(",")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

cnt_sum = counts.values().sum()

sc.parallelize([cnt_sum]).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("<path>/filename.txt")
```

**More effective (less code):**

```
count = len(rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(",")).collect())
sc.parallelize([count]).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("<path>/filename.txt")
```

Comment: I need to use RDD.

Comment: Can you describe your use case ? Think I'm lost a little here!

Comment: I have a file that was split into a list of elements [item1,item,2,item3, item4,etc] and I want to count the total number of item in this list ( I know that there are 43367 items). I need to write this count, i.e. (43367) to a  file using RDDs only. The output should look like: Count: 43367

Comment: Added, a more effective way to achieve this